# Enable button when scroll bootstrap modal to bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I want to force the user to read all the agreement inside the modal. The idea is simple, if they don't scroll to the last line of the text. The button still disable. But the button is not enable. This is my code:

Javascript:

```
$('#agreement').scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() == $(this)[0].scrollHeight - $(this).height()) {            
        $('#closeBtn').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

As for the clearer picture. I put the code in js here : http://jsfiddle.net/h3WDq/1129/

This is an update version from @BG101. The button enable when I scroll to the bottom but it keeps enable even the modal button is click again. http://jsfiddle.net/h3WDq/1132/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your `modal-body` need the scroll event, and you need a small change to the `if`:-

```
$('.modal-body').scroll(function () {
    if ($('#agreement').height() == ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height())) {         
        $('#closeBtn').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

working snippet below **(updated to toggle on/off)**

```js
$('.modal-body').scroll(function() {
  var disable = $('#agreement').height() != ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height());
  $('#closeBtn').prop('disabled', disable);
});
```

```css
.btn-group {
  z-index: 1051;
}
.modal-body {
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

  <h3>User Agreement</h3>

  <!-- Button to trigger modal -->
  <div>
    <a href="#myModal1" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch Modal</a>
  </div>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div id="myModal1" class="modal hide" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
      <h3>User Agreement</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">

      <div id="agreement" style="height:1000px;">
        A very long agreement
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button id="closeBtn" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" disabled>I Accept</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Is is possible to  disable when the scroll far from the bottom too? I tried `else` with adding the attribute `disabled` back. But it's not work : `$('#closeBtn').removeAttr('disabled');`

Comment: Super! This is what the world is looking for :D Thank you very much.

Comment: Dude, your example works fine with google chrome, but in Mozilla Firefox, it's not working. Any solution??

Answer (score 3):

`#terms-page` - is the ID of the particular `div`

You can try the following:

```
$("#terms-page").scroll(function () {
    var ele = document.getElementById('terms-page');
    if (ele.scrollHeight - ele.scrollTop === ele.clientHeight)
    {
        $('#closeBtn').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

Comment: I had to use `(ele.scrollHeight - ele.scrollTop - ele.clientHeight < 10)` because there was a missmatch by 0.5 when comparing. For me it was fine to have a range and not be at the very bottom

Answer (score 0):

Why not put a hidden element at the bottom of the agreement and detect when the offset of that element is scrolled to the top?

```
$('#agreement').scroll(function () {
    var target = $("#target").offset().top;
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= target) {
        $('#closeBtn').removeAttr('disabled');
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove Height from div and paste the below code and it will work super

```
$('.modal-body').scroll(function() {
   var height = $('#agreement').height();
   console.log(height);
   var scroll = $(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height();
   console.log(scroll);
   if (height>scroll) {
     $('#closeBtn').prop('disabled', true);
   } else {
     $('#closeBtn').prop('disabled', false);
   }
});
```

Comment: It helps if you explain your code.