# How to enabled true or false a button when scrolling at the end of a PDF?

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, scroll

I have a modal with one PDF and a button **enabled="false"** and I'm tryind to do is when I finish the scroll in the PDF chagne to **enabled="true"** and I don't know how to do this.

[image]

**HTML and ASPx**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <input runat="server" type="hidden" id="hDocumento_id" />
        <input id="hUsuario" type="hidden" runat="server"/>
        <dx:ASPxCallback ID="CQFUNCIONES" ClientInstanceName="CQFUNCIONES" runat="server" >
            <ClientSideEvents  CallbackComplete ="function(s, e){Redireccionar(e.result);}" />
        </dx:ASPxCallback>
        <div class="wraper-popup">
            <div class="popup-body">
                <div class="innerPopup">
                    <iframe style="width:100%; height:100%;" id="iframeAbsolute" runat="server" src="" frameborder="0"  marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" typeof="application/pdf" ></iframe>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <div><asp:Label ID="lblResultado" runat="server" ForeColor ="Red" Text="* Este documento se ha aceptado correctamente. Por favor, espere a que el sistema pueda gestionar la firma del documento. "></asp:Label></div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>

       <%-- <dx:ASPxCallbackPanel ID="cbViewer" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="callbackPanel">
            <PanelCollection>
                <dx:PanelContent runat="server" SupportsDisabledAttribute="True">
                   <uc:PdfViewer ID="viewer" runat="server" PdfFilePath="FallCatalog.pdf" />
                </dx:PanelContent>
            </PanelCollection>
        </dx:ASPxCallbackPanel>--%>
        <dx:ASPxButton ID="btnFirmar" ClientInstanceName="btnFirmar" runat="server" Theme="MaterialCompact" Text="Aceptar" ClientEnabled="true" AutoPostBack="false" >
            <ClientSideEvents Click="function(s,e){ verificarRespuestas();}" />
        </dx:ASPxButton> 
    </form>
```

In this HTML shows the modal with the PDF embed and the button

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        //$(function () {

        //    $(".innerPopup").mCustomScrollbar({
        //        axis: "y",
        //        scrollButtons: { enable: true },
        //        theme: "rounded-dots-dark",
        //        scrollInertia: '20',
        //        advanced: { autoExpandHorizontalScroll: true },
        //        callbacks: {
        //            onTotalScroll: function () {
        //                btnFirmar.SetEnabled(true);
        //            }
        //        }
        //    });

        //    var $vpH = $(window.top).height();
        //    $('.iframeAbsolute').height($vpH);
        //})
        function verificarRespuestas() {
            CQFUNCIONES.PerformCallback(document.getElementById('hDocumento_id').value);
        }

        function Redireccionar(value) {
            var resultado = value;
            if (resultado == 1) {
                //window.parent.abreCuestionario(document.getElementById('hDocumento_id').value);
                mostrarConfirmarCorreo();
            } else {
                mostrarConfirmarCorreo();

                //window.parent.enviar_post(document.getElementById('hDocumento_id').value);
            }
        }

        function mostrarConfirmarCorreo() {
            BootstrapDialog.show({
                title: 'Confirmar e-mail',
                message: function (dialog) {
                    var $content = $('<div><h5>Por favor, indique su correo electrónico.</h5><input type="email" name="direccionemail" id="direccionemail" class="form-control"><h5>Confirme su correo electrónico.</h5><input type="email" name="direccionemailConfirma" id="direccionemailConfirma" class="form-control"></div>');
                    return $content;
                },
                closable: false,

                buttons: [{
                    label: 'Cancelar',
                    action: function (dialog) {
                        dialog.close();
                        window.parent.cerrar_cuestionario();
                    }
                }, {
                    label: 'Aceptar',
                    cssClass: 'btn-primary',
                    action: function (dialog) {
                        var $mail = $('#direccionemail').val();
                        var $mailConfir = $('#direccionemailConfirma').val();

                        if (typeof $mail == "undefined" || $mail == "" || $mail == null) {
                            window.top.mostrarModal('Atención!', 'Introduzca una dirección de correo');
                        } else {
                            if ($mail !== $mailConfir) {
                                window.top.mostrarModal('Atención!', 'La direcciones de correo no coinciden');
                            } else {
                                window.parent.enviar_post(document.getElementById('hDocumento_id').value, $mail);
                                dialog.close();
                            }

                        }

                    }

                }]
            });
        }
    </script>
```

I watched some examples here but when I try to do them in my code doesn't work.

I watch these examples:

[Enable button when scroll bootstrap modal to bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35008823/enable-button-when-scroll-bootstrap-modal-to-bottom)

[Using jQuery, how do I force a visitor to scroll to the bottom of a textarea to enable the submit button?](http://jsfiddle.net/ETLZ8/)

I'm front end developer and in the job told me to do this and when I watch the code, is ASPx and it's the ASPx that shows all the code HTML

Can you help me please?

Thanks

Comment: HI, you want to enable/disable scrollbar of PDF on button click?

Comment: no, I want to enabled/disabled the button when the pdf scroll finish

Comment: Ok, i dont know ASPx but i can tell you that if you can get when the iframe ends scrolling to bottom end it triggers the button to enable/disable. For this, you have to use jquery and use this plugin of it. http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

Comment: in the example of **Enable Button when scroll** [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35008823/enable-button-when-scroll-bootstrap-modal-to-bottom] the first answer is what I want to do, but there, the button is HTML and mine is ASPx andwhen I try to do that function, doesn't works

Comment: HTML loads on DOM so to apply any event to the button result in its action added to it. But in ASPx, i think this event is not calling. You have to research more on button event calling on ASPx. You will find it easily.

Comment: I've never worked with ASPx, I'm a front end developer and I can do this with HTML and JQuery but if the button is ASPx I don't know how do it, I'm looking for and only watch in internet examples such I put in the description

Comment: I am same as you, so may be, someone who knows ASPx will tell you more about it.

Comment: Thanks SaurabhLP. Please, somebody how got knowledge with ASPx can help me please?